# mapviewballoons error

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have recently stumbled into this really neat api for showing callOutbubbles in android MapView. I just have a problem with this api, when i am trying to implement the api following the examples i get this error:

```
05-02 14:13:19.847: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.readystatesoftware.mapviewballoons.R$layout
```

And i am getting this warning right before the error:

```
05-02 14:13:19.838: W/dalvikvm(11857): VFY: unable to resolve static field 590 (balloon_overlay) in Lcom/readystatesoftware/mapviewballoons/R$layout;
```

Any of you got the same problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have included MapViewBallon project as library (if not then post the details, and also the link of project which you are referring to).
Do following steps:

- Clear all your references project library (from *ProjectProperties > Android > Library*).
- Clean your project using *Project>Clean*.
- Add the library projects again.
- build and install.

Comment: Thanks man... I have added it wrong :P ... I added the jar file from the balloon project in my libs... Now i added the project as a library in the setup... it works :) thanks :D